# element layout with jqueryui.resizeable() and angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have elements on a template laid out as such

```
div id(stageWrapper) class(mainWrapper)
    div id(swfPanel) class(panel panel-primary)
        div id(swfStage) class(swfWrapper)
            div id(swfObject) class(tf-container) /div
        /div
    /div

    div id(chatPanel) class(panel panel-primary)
        div id(chatWrapper) class(chatWrap) /div
    /div
/div
```

I am using resizable() from the jqueryui library on the swfPanel and when i load my fideo inside of the tf-container the video will resize itself to a point ....

the problem is that the video will wind up being taller than the containing div ... it resizes perfectly based on height but it will resize vertically to maintain its own aspect ratio.

How do i use the resizeable() functionality ... resize the swfStage  ... maintain the aspect ration of the video ... AND keep the video safe and snug inside the parent divs at all times??